# Create the array of integer with consecutive number in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
+---+-----+------------+
| ID|  pos|       value|
+---+-----+------------+
| A1|    0|         ABC|
| A1|    1|         BCD|
| A1|    2|         CDF|
| A1|    5|         ABC|
| A1|    8|         FGR|
| A1|    9|         EFD|
| A2|    0|         L_1|
| A2|    1|         L_2|
| A2|    3|         STU|
+---+-----+------------+
```

The expected output is:

```
+---+-------------+-----------------------------+
| ID|     arr(pos)|                   arr(value)|
+---+-------------+-----------------------------+
| A1|    [0, 1, 2]|        ['ABC', 'BCD', 'CDF']|
| A1|          [5]|                      ['ABC']|
| A1|       [8, 9]|               ['FGR', 'EFD']|
| A2|       [0, 1]|               ['L_1', 'L_2']|
| A2|          [3]|                      ['STU']|
+---+-----+-------+-----------------------------+
```

The meaning of this output is to `groupby` with the `ID` column and also `collect_list` in both the `pos` and `value` columns. Importantly, for an `ID`, the list of `pos` has to be consecutive. If the previous and next `pos` of an ID is not consecutive like the `ID=A1` with `pos=5`, then it will be an array with a single value.

For an `ID`, the value of `pos` is not duplicated.

I tried using the `lag` column to create the previous and next index but I don't know how to transform from that.

```py
window = W.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("pos")

df = (
    df
    .withColumn("prev_pos", F.lag(F.col('pos'), 1).over(window))
    .withColumn("next_pos", F.lag(F.col('pos'), -1).over(window))
)
```

I have this output with this code but I don't know how to identify the consecutive pattern.

```
+---+-----+------------+---------+---------+
| ID|  pos|       value| prev_pos| next_pos|
+---+-----+------------+---------+---------+
| A1|    0|         ABC|     null|        1|
| A1|    1|         BCD|        0|        2|
| A1|    2|         CDF|        1|        5|
| A1|    5|         ABC|        2|        8|
| A1|    8|         FGR|        5|        9|
| A1|    9|         EFD|        8|     null|
| A2|    0|         L_1|     null|        1|
| A2|    1|         L_2|        0|        3|
| A2|    3|         STU|        1|     null|
+---+-----+------------+---------+---------+
```

Another approach I tried is:

```
df = (
    df
    .groupby("ID")
    .agg(
        F.sort_array(F.collect_list(F.struct("pos", "value")))
        .alias("pos_list")
    )
    .withColumn("arr(pos)", F.col("pos_list.pos"))
    .withColumn("arr(value)", F.col("pos_list.value"))
    .drop("pos_list")
)
```

Then I will have this output but I don't know how to split the array when the number is not consecutive:

```
+---+--------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| ID|            arr(pos)|                                   arr(value)|
+---+--------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| A1|  [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 9]|   ['ABC', 'BCD', 'CDF', 'ABC', 'FGR', 'EFD']|
| A2|           [0, 1, 3]|                        ['L_1', 'L_2', 'STU']|
+---+--------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Code for creating the input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('A1', 0, 'ABC'),
     ('A1', 1, 'BCD'),
     ('A1', 2, 'CDF'),
     ('A1', 5, 'ABC'),
     ('A1', 8, 'FGR'),
     ('A1', 9, 'EFD'),
     ('A2', 0, 'L_1'),
     ('A2', 1, 'L_2'),
     ('A2', 2, 'STU')],
    ['ID', 'pos', 'value'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

```
W = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('pos')

# Compare the current and previous row
# in the pos column to create a boolean mask
mask = ((F.col('pos') - F.lag('pos').over(W)) != 1).cast('int')

# Calculate cumulative sum over the boolean mask to create blocks
# these blocks will identify different groups of monotonic rows
blocks = F.sum(F.when(mask.isNull(), 0).otherwise(mask)).over(W)

# Aggregate function to collect list of struct(pos, value) 
# per ID and blocks
posval = F.array_sort(F.collect_list(F.struct('pos', 'value')))

# Groupby and aggregate then transform the list 
# of structs to extract pos and value
result = (
    df
    .withColumn('blocks', blocks)
    .groupBy('ID', 'blocks')
    .agg(posval['pos'].alias('pos'), 
         posval['value'].alias('value'))
    .drop('blocks')
)
```

---

```
result.show()

+---+---------+---------------+
| ID|      pos|          value|
+---+---------+---------------+
| A1|[0, 1, 2]|[ABC, BCD, CDF]|
| A1|      [5]|          [ABC]|
| A1|   [8, 9]|     [FGR, EFD]|
| A2|   [0, 1]|     [L_1, L_2]|
| A2|      [3]|          [STU]|
+---+---------+---------------+
```